# Getting an undefined object before the object is populated

Tags: reactjs, giphy-api

So I'm building just a small web app that takes data from the giphy API and then displays it.
Bear with me. This is a long one.

```
export const fetchTrending = async () => {
try {
    const {data:{data}} = await axios.get('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=4A40i9pS4hOK6N3f77WYflnhZe93UIB4&limit=5&rating=g')
    return data;

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

Then the data goes to app.js

```
  class App extends React.Component{
  state={
    data:[{}]
  }

   async componentDidMount(){
     const response = await fetchTrending();
     this.setState({data:response})
   }

  render(){
    const {data} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <img className={styles.ad1} src="https://media.giphy.com/headers/2020-07-27-05-1595862312/NBA_BANNER_HP.gif" />
        <Trending data={data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

From there to its final destination.

```
export const Trending = ({data:data}) => {

  const images = data[0].images;
  console.log(images);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className={styles.trending}>TRENDING Gifs</h2>
      
    </div>
  );
};
```

The API which is here https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=4A40i9pS4hOK6N3f77WYflnhZe93UIB4&limit=5&rating=g consists of data, meta and pagination.
All I want is the url which is in downsized in the images object of the each data object. But each time I try to destructure it. It gives me the undefined object error no matter what I try. Again, apologies for the long description. If I hadn't wrote all of this you wouldn't understand.

The error I'm getting is this.

```
Cannot destructure property 'downsized' of 'images' as it is undefined.
Trending
/src/Components/Trending/Trending.jsx:8
   5 | export const Trending = ({data:data}) => {
   6 | 
   7 |   const images = data[0].images;
>  8 |   const {downsized} = images;
   9 |   console.log(downsized);
  10 |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCQNC.png)

also getting an undefined object . Why????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state is empty:

```js
state={
    data:[{}]
  }
```

Before the giphy api is called and the result is set as the state (it's an asynchronous operation), this object is passed to the `Trending` component

```js
<Trending data={data} />
```

Inside the Trending component, you access the property `images` of the first element:

```js
const images = data[0].images;
const {downsized} = images;
```

But your initial data is `[{}]`, so `data[0] = {}` and therefore `data[0].images` is undefined. Then, you try to access the property `downsized` on an undefined item!

```js
const data = [{}}

data[0]; // => {}
data[0].images; // => undefined
data[0].images.downsized // => ERROR!
```

You need to check if images exists before trying to access the downsized property

```
const downsized = images ? images.downsized : null
```

Comment: Ok. This worked. Now comes the next problem. As you can see there are 5 total objects.
i want to get to the url of all those object and create new img element with that url as it's source in the trending file. How do I dot it?? I tried mapping but the same error pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You have async componentDidMount and an async fetch yet you are not waiting for the data before trying to access it.

```
export const Trending = ({data:data}) => {

  // ***Dont try to access it if it doesn't exist yet.***
  if (!data[0].images) return <div />

  const images = data[0].images;
  console.log(images);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className={styles.trending}>TRENDING Gifs</h2>
      
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `data[0]` exists, but it is an empty object. `!data || !data[0]` would return false

Comment: Because you defined it in state as an empty object. Set it to null.